# weblogic jax-ws multithreading

Tags: weblogic12c

I am using Eclipse + Oracle Enterprise Pack to write some jax-ws based service. It works fine in my development mode (composed WSDL, generated Weblogic web service stub code, completed the detail, and tested code from client), one by one. But when I moved these services into a public testing server (running WL 12c (12.1.1) the web service handler looks like is single threaded. This does not make sense to me, but from my app log, one service was running and then all other requests had to wait until the first one completed its task.

What had I missed in my stub code or configuration setting (I just used default server setting)? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Alan

Comment: My bad. I used built-in GUI testing tool and that is the problem. I fired multiple requests from my Eclipse app client and it's fine.

Comment: Note that jax-ws is not threadsafe. http://cxf.apache.org/faq#FAQ-AreJAX-WSclientproxiesthreadsafe?